# how to find license information about Visual Studio 2019 Pro by using powershell?

Tags: powershell, registry

I am making a licensing tracking tool for all software and apps installed on each machine. For starters, I want to make a Powershell script to find a license for Visual Studio 2019 Pro.

I was able to output the result locally with the following code:

```
## Define a regedit path for your target software
## Visual Studio 2019 Professional
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration\XXXXX'

## Create an object
$data = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

## Check if the software is installed by checking the path
if(Test-Path $path){
    $data | Add-member -NotePropertyName 'Visual Studio 2019 Professional' -NotePropertyValue (Get-ItemProperty -Path $path).ProductID
} else {
    $data | Add-member -NotePropertyName 'Visual Studio 2019 Professional' -NotePropertyValue null
}

## Return Name and Value
$data.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Property Name, Value
```

**Result**

```
Name                            Value                  
----                            -----                  
Visual Studio 2019 Professional XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

However, the last 5 digits in the path of regedit (i.e. `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration\XXXXX`) are different for each users.

Basically, I want to track other users' licenses as well under the same domain. How can I do this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration*

Comment: Your answer is lacking in explanation. It assumes that the OP knows what `HKLM:` means and is unclear to those who do not recognize that term. proved with additional supporting information. Please [Edit] to add that information, thank you.